# Static resources not showing up in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

Messing round with a simple react + webpack app, however I'm having issues debugging because the static resources don't seem to be loading in dev tools (and I can't work out why breakpoints aren't working!)

Got the following in my webpack.config.js file:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        loader: ['babel-loader'],
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: 'babel_cache',
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: { warnings: false },
      mangle: true,
      sourcemap: false,
      beautify: false,
      dead_code: true
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
  ]
};
```

And my express app serves up the /dist folder:

```
app.use('/static', Express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));
```

However, when I try to view the source code (using a sourcemap), my dev tools is only showing the following:

[image: dev tools]

When I navigate to localhost:3000/static/bundle.js and localhost:3000/static/bundle.js.map it shows the files in plaintext. My app also 'works' (ie. the JS is being used) but it doesn't seem to show in Chrome. Am I missing something very obvious here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please don't use `UglifyJs, Dedupe` plugins in development mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found a way to do this, just incase you're reading this in the future.

The issue I had was that I was using index.ejs to display the markup:

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"><%- markup -%></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
return res.render('index', { markup });
```

I wasn't including `dist/bundle.js` into my .ejs file, and this meant that Chrome Tools didn't pick it up. I added `<script src="static/bundle.js"></script>` to my index.ejs (even though not strictly necessary for the code to work!) and it began to appear in chrome dev tools at last.

I can now finally set breakpoints in my code and debug, as well as opening my .js files in the Source tab, so all appears to be working fine.

I'd be interested to hear if there's another way of doing this, one that doesn't involve needlessly getting the bundle.js script in the html.